# embeding a list in class property and calling it's values

Tags: python, class, list

If I have class as following:

```
class theater:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__seatMatrix=[10]*5
        self.__seats=seating[0]
        self.__rows=len(seating)
```

How can I implement a get/setter to update the values for seats?
The idea is that seating=[10]*5, 5 rows with 10 seats.
I've been turning my head around this for the entire weekend.
When i try:

```
def getseats(self):
        self.__seats
```

It does not return anything.

/Andy

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget the return statement in your function implementation. Unlike some other languages, Python does not automatically return the last expression that was evaluated in the function. The return value from a function with no `return` statement is `None`.

In this case, your `getseats()` method should be:

```
def getseats(self):
    return self.__seats
```

As an aside, if you want to designate certain variables in your class as semi-private (I say semi since fully private variables don't really exist), the convention in Python is to use a single underscore (so `self._seats` rather than `self.__seats`). Instance variables prefixed with a double underscore actually get name mangled to try and enforce their designation as private, which can produce surprising results if that's not what you intended.

The python docs explain this best: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables

Answer (score 1):

You can use a property to wrap a getter/setter pair for the seats:

```
@property
def seats(self): return self.__seats 
# As Jarret pointed out, don't forget the return value

@seats.setter
def seats(self, value): self.__seats = value
```

Or you can implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` to treat the object as if it were a list of seats:

```
def __getitem__(self, index): return self.__seats[index]

def __setitem__(self, index, value): self.__seats[index] = value
```

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, don't use double leadning underscores unless you are *sure* you need to. This is not Java, you don't have to have private class members. That said, this is not the reason you have a problem, it's the lack of the return statement, as somebody with a keener eye than me saw.

Anyway, this is how to implement it in Python:

```
class Theater:
  self __init__(self, seating)
   self.seating = seating
   self.seats = seating[0]
   self.rows = len(seating)
```

Done. Note the complete lack of getters and setters, you don't need them. *Stop trying to hide your data from yourself.* In any case, you can't.

```
>>> class Theater:
...    def __init__(self, data):
...       self.__private_data = data
... 
>>> t = Theater("Private data")
>>> t._Theater__private_data
'Private data'
```

Oh, I guess it wasn't that private anyway. Python does *not* have private members. This is *not* Java.